# Linearly Equivalence of pullback of divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X_0=\mathbb{P}^2$ and $\eta: X_r \mapsto X_0$ be the blow-up of $p_1,\cdots, p_r$, where $p_1 \in X_0$. In a paper I am reading, the author states the following: If $C\subset X_r$ is an irreducible curve that is equal to the strict transform of some curve $D\subset \mathbb{P}^2$, then $C$ must be linearly equivalent to $$dL-\sum_i m_iE_i$$ where $d$ is the degree of $D$,  and $L$ and the $E_i$'s are given in the Picard group decomposition: $\text{Pic}(X_r)=\mathbb{Z}L \oplus \mathbb{Z}E_1\oplus\cdots \oplus\mathbb{Z}E_r$.

The author stated that this is due to the fact that one has $\pi^\ast(D)=\tilde{D} + m_p E$ where $\tilde{D}$ is the strict-transform of $D$. However, I am unable to see why this formula leads to the linear equivalence stated above. Can any one help enlighten me? THank you very much.

Comment: "I am unable to see why this is so." It is not clear which you are asking about: the given expression for $\pi^*(D)$, or the author's claim that this expression implies the expression written above for the class of $C$. Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm referring to the latter: Why the expression given above is implied by the one below. Sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify, I'll assume $r=1$ and the field $k$ has characteristic zero (maybe unnecessary).

Seen as Cartier divisor $D$ is given by $(U_i,\{f_i=0\})$ for an affine open covering $\mathbb{P}^2 = \cup U_i$. Since $\pi\colon X_1\backslash E \to \mathbb{P}^2\backslash \{p_1\}$ is an isomorphism, we restrict to a neighborhood of $p_1$.

Let $x,y$ be generators of the maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2,p_1}$ and let $f(x,y)=0$ be a local equation for $D$. Then 
$$
f(x,y) = \sum_{i+j \geq m} a_{ij}x^iy^j
$$
where $m=m_{p_1}(D)$ is the multiplicity. On the other hand, the blow-up is locally given by two charts $V_1,(x,t)$ and $V_2,(u,y)$ and 
$$
\pi(x,t) = (x,xt), \,\pi(u,y) = (uy,y).
$$
Note that $E\cap  V_1 = \{ x=0\}$ and $E\cap V_2 = \{y=0\}$. It follows that the pull back of $D$ is defined on $V_1$ by
$$
f\circ \pi (x,t) = \sum_{i+j \geq m} a_{ij}x^{i+j}t^{j} = x^mg(x,t)
$$
where $x$ does not divide $g$ and $\{g=0\}$ is the equation of the strict transform of $D$. On the other chart we have the same.

Hence $\pi^\ast(D) = \bar D+ mE$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! May I also clarify something. When we talk about the 'blowup at say $V_1$' what we are actually talking about? Are we referring to the preimage of $D$ under $\pi^{-1}$ in $V_1\cap E$?

Comment: I know that the chart $V_1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2$. Hence I view the coordinate change $(x,y)\mapsto (x,xy)$ as the composite of $\pi$ with this isomorphism. How can we assert that the new $f$ (after the change of coordinates) is the pull back in $V_1$? I thought we have to consider the preimage of it under $\pi$. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: Where I say blow-up I mean the variety $X_1$, the blow-up od $\mathbb{P}^2$ at the point $p_1$.

Comment: I fixed some coordinates in order to describe $\pi$  but the multiplicity is invariant by change of coordinates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @AlanMuniz I agree that what you did shows that $\pi^*(C)$ has a zero at $E$ with multiplicity $m$. But how do I know that $\widetilde{D}$ is a simple zero? And that there are no other zeros (or poles) except these ones?

Comment: @rmdmc89 Well, we have started with a Cartier divisor  $D$ and worked out that its strict trandform is $\pi^\ast (D) - m_p(D)E$ nothing said about $D$ being reduced or irreducible. However, since $\pi$ is an isomorphism outside $E$, we can infer that $D$ is reduced or irreducible if and only if its strict transform is so.